# angular child html referencing component declared in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, inheritance, reference, components

Embarrassed at what must be simple concept:

```
app.module
    declares  NavComponent  <-- to be used see below
              SplashPage    <-- successfully references NavComponent
    exports   NavComponent
    imports   PreRegistrationModule

PreRegistrationModule   <- a "child" of app module
    imports   OverviewModule

  OverViewModule        <- a "child of PreRegistration module
      declares  HowToUseThisProgramComponent

    HowToUseThisProgramComponent   <- a "child of OverView module
        HowToUse.html  contains  <app-nav></app-nav>  <- defined in NavComponent
```

My (mis)understanding is that I should be able to use NavComponent's  in the HowToUseThisProgram.html because it is a descendant of app.module where NavComponent is declared (and  exported).

I get ERROR 'app-nav' is not a known element...  however, app-nav is working fine in SplashPage component, which is at the same level as PreRegistration Module.

I can't 'import' NavComponent to any child module as that (I think) makes NavComponent a child of more than one module (illegal).

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance, Chuck ("Yogi")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the NavComponent belongs to the AppModule and it doesn't belong to  OverViewModule. On the other hand, you can use it right in the SplashPage because both are in the same module.

If you want to use the NavComponent you should create a new Module where you can declare it, exported it and then you should import in the AppModule and the OverViewModule.

For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavComponent,
  ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```

Then in the AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedComponentsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally in the OverViewModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HowToUseThisProgramComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedComponentsModule
  ],
})
export class OverViewModule { }
```